# How do I deploy my backend and frontend using nginx?

Tags: reactjs, amazon-web-services, api, express, nginx

```
server{
    listen 80 ;
    listen [::]:80;
    server_name test.demo.io;
    root /home/ubuntu/SuperApp/build;
    location / {
        try_files $uri /index.html;

    }
}
```

this is my nginx config file for frontend that is developed in react js.

I have also developed backed in express js.

Now how shall I deploy my express js backend code.?

Shall I keep these two projects separate and run the backend on port 3000 ? In that case, will I have to do additional things to connect my front end  with this express js through apis? As both app are not running on same port?

Or shall I keep my front end in the express js static files and run the whole app from port 3000? but in that case how would I attach my current domain to the website as  currently I haven't attach any port no like 3000 used.

Please help. I am new to this.

Answer (score 0):

Front-end and back-end are two separate projects
you build the front-end adding api url as env var during the build process. you just deploy the static build result on Nginx server.

you run the api separately e.g on http://localhost:3000 using a command like `npm start` or `node server.js` depends on your back-end code

Comment: could you answer here? https://stackoverflow.com/questions/73139207/how-do-i-access-my-api-that-is-deployed-on-a-server
@Ahmed Abdelazim