# How do I access my api that is deployed on a server?

Tags: api, express, http, amazon-ec2, backend

```
app.use((req,res,next)=>{
    res.setHeader('Access-Control-Allow-Origin','*');
})
```

I used this code in my express js backend.
Then deployed it on server and run my app using `node index`

But then I tried to access my api from localhost using this - **public IPV4 address of ec2 (aws):3000/getData**

But it didn't work. **error : {"message":"connect ETIMEDOUT 172.31.2.86:5432"}**.

What did I miss?

Comment: Did you open port `3000` in the security group attached to the EC2 instance?

Answer (score 0):

check AWS security group config. port 3000 is blocked by default